# gutter space in-between fluid columns

Tags: css, html

I'm looking into writing my own grid system, and I have a simple question.

If I were to have two half columns

eg.

```
 .container {
      width: 100%;
 }

 .half-width {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
 }

 <div class="half-width">a</div>
 <div class="half-width">b</div>
```

How best to tweak that to actually have some margin in between each container (first one should have some margin right where as the second should ideally have some margin left?) or "gutter space"?

Does that mean tuning down the 50% to something more like 48%?

http://jsfiddle.net/ejmczevw/2

Comment: not necessarily. you could put some padding in there.

Comment: In addition to what Marc said; when using padding to create gutter space you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to maintain the original width without needing to change the size to compensate. (Example: `width: 50%; padding-right: 5%; box-sizing: border-box;`)

Comment: here's what I'm getting

http://jsfiddle.net/ejmczevw/

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` will affect anything from the border inwards. Margins are counted as outside the border, use padding instead.

Comment: how do I create some gutter space in-between the two containers by using just box-sizing: border-box and padding?

Comment: I've updated your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ejmczevw/1/ using the padding and border-box.

Comment: visually, I'm looking for something more like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ejmczevw/2/

Comment: You can create that by using the example I gave above by using each half as containers to hold further content (like the bordered boxes) instead of using each half as immediate content.

Comment: use this `width: calc(50% - 5%);` for `5%` `margin` eg [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ejmczevw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But if you want a Space between the border of the boxes you need to put them into your column div.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
 }

.half-width {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right 8px;
}

<div class="half-width">a</div>
<div class="half-width">b</div>
```

I added an example for this here
http://jsfiddle.net/g1yLpbwp/

Comment: your jsfiddle has different code than the one you've written here

Comment: Yes because I changed it according to your information from the comments above, that you would like to have a border around the elements. So I build it as BurpmanJunior also suggested. Using the grid as a container for the elements with the border.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the padding on both sides (right/left)

```
.container {
width: 100%;
}

.half-width {
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
width: 50%;
float: left;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right 8px;
}
```

Or you can remove the left and right padding of the first and last div respectively

```
.half-width:first-child {
padding-left: 0px;

}
.half-width:last-child {
padding-right 0px;
}
```

check this if it works.